# issue about convert html to pdf use html2pdf in python2.7

Tags: python, html, pdf, html2pdf, pisa

when i render a html, it`s normal, however when i convert it to pdf use pisa：

```
def render_html2pdf_stream_pisa(template_src, context_dict):

    template = get_template(template_src)

    context = Context(context_dict)

    html = template.render(context)
    try:
        result = StringIO.StringIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")),
                                dest=result,
                                encoding="UTF-8",
                                )
        if not pdf.err:
            return result.getvalue()
    except Exception,e:
        print Exception(e)

    return None
```

as the result, the pdf is half-baked, not full pdf file like html`s style;

i don`t know where the issue

Comment: i solved it use pdfkit, but i dont`d find a method to solve it use pisa